# JAXB XmlJavaAdapter working with Interface with @XmlAnyElement not with @XmlElement

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an implementation of XmlAdapter class as follows:

```
public class XMLSimpleElementAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Element, String> {

protected static final DocumentImpl doc=new DocumentImpl(true);

protected String elementName;
protected String nameSpace;

public XMLSimpleElementAdapter() {
    this("Description","https://www.proviseconsulting.com/ProcessDataModelDefinition");
}

public XMLSimpleElementAdapter(String elementName, String nameSpace) {

    this.elementName=elementName;
    this.nameSpace=nameSpace;

}//constructor closing

@Override
public Element marshal(String value) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("XMLSimpleElementAdapter -- marshal called");

    Element element=doc.createElement(elementName);
    element.setAttribute("xmlns", nameSpace);

    if(value!=null) {

        Node textValue=doc.createTextNode(value);
        element.appendChild(textValue);

    }//if closing

    return (Element)element;

}//marshal closing

@Override
public String unmarshal(Element element) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("XMLSimpleElementAdapter -- unmarshal called");

    String value="Some hard coded value";

    try {
    System.out.println("Element = "+element.getParentNode());
    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    Node textValue=element.getFirstChild();
    if(textValue!=null) {value=textValue.getNodeValue();}

    return value;

}//unmarshal closing
  }//class closing
```

I am using the adapter on an attribute of a class:

```
@XmlAnyElement
//@XmlElement(name="Description",namespace="https://www.proviseconsulting.com/TriggerConfig")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = XMLSimpleElementAdapter.class)
protected String description;
```

Where the XML is: `<Description>This is the description of the configuration.</Description>`

It works perfectly and I get the value. However, if I use the commented '@XmlElement' annotation instead of @XmlAnyElement, I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main"   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.w3c.dom.Element is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.w3c.dom.Element
        at protected java.lang.String com.provise.wfm.trigger.config.TriggerConfigImpl.description
        at com.provise.wfm.trigger.config.TriggerConfigImpl
```

Am I missing something, JAXB can handle org.W3c.dom.Element with @XmlAnyType and not with @XmlElement type??

I am using JAXB implementation from Sun/Oracle with JDK 12 (AdoptOpenJDK with J9)

Comment: JAXB is not defined by Java SE since Java SE 11 so you should probably mention which version of JAXB you are using.

Comment: Right, I am using the following: <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>

Comment: Did you find a solution?